# Given a data set, what is the probability that a sample value is over a certain threshold?

Tags: probability, statistics

Say I have a data set, and I've calculated the mean and the standard deviation.

It seems pretty common to find the probability that a sample would be in a certain interval centered on the mean with a radius that is an integer multiple of the standard deviation. But what I want to do is find the probability that a sample is over (or under) a certain value. That value can be anything.

Assume a normal distribution.

How can I find this?

I'm sure the answer to this question exists already, but I wasn't sure how to word the question very well, so I couldn't find it.

Comment: This depends on the distribution, there is no exact answer in general.  [Chebyshev's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality) may help.

Comment: @lulu I meant normal distribution. I'll edit to say that.

Comment: Not following.  If all you have is data, then you don't know the underlying distribution.  You can measure things, like mean and variance, but that can't tell you what distribution you are dealing with.  Of course, in lots of situations one has, or can generate, a model of the situation.  That would tend to come with a distribution (with parameters that you can calibrate to your data). And then you can answer the question within that model.

Comment: Oh, well if you specify normal then it is just a matter of integration.  Or look up table.

Comment: Excel, say, has the cumulative normal as a standard function.  Most computational packages will.

Comment: @lulu So "cumulative normal" is what I should be looking for? I'll see if I can find that.

Comment: To be clear;  in standard packages, like Excel, one measures $P(x≤a)$.  In excel the code is $Normdist(a, \mu, \sigma, 1)$.  What you want is just $1-P(x≤a)$. Note;  the $1$ at the end is what makes it "cumulative".  If you change it to $0$ you get the value of the density function at $a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing the mean and the standard deviation is in general not enough to know the full cumulative density function (which is what you basically want to know).

If you suspect the probability law behind the data to be "simple", such as a Gaussian, then you can plug the mean/standard deviation into the formula of the cdf to obtain estimation of the probabilities you are searching for.

For example, if you have $\theta$ as mean and $\sigma$ as standard deviation for a normal r.v., then : $$P(a < X < b )=P(X<b) - P(X<a)$$$$ P(a < X < b )=\frac 1 2  \left( 1+ erf\left( \frac{b-\theta}{\sqrt 2 \sigma} \right) \right)-\frac 1 2  \left( 1+ erf\left( \frac{a-\theta}{\sqrt 2 \sigma} \right) \right)$$

with $erf$ the error function.

Just plug the $\theta$ and $\sigma$ you have estimated.